# HTML5 Video: Hiding controls does not work in internet explorer, removeAttr, removeProp, etc

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-video

Trying to hide and show the video controls on hover enter / hover leave:

```
$('#content-video').hover(function(event) {
   if(event.type === "mouseenter") {
      console.log("ENTER");
      $(this).attr("controls", true);
  } else if(event.type === "mouseleave") {
      console.log("EXIT");
      $(this).attr("controls", false);
      $(this).prop("controls", false);
      $(this).removeAttr("controls");
      $(this).removeProp("controls");
      currentVideo.removeAttribute('controls');
  }
})
```

Have tried everything. The ENTER and EXIT messages show properly, as expected, in Internet explorer, but the 'controls="true"' stays on the element and the controls stay visible on mouseleave! Any ideas why? Grumble.

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: You can try .control-bar {
  display: none;
} where .control-bar is the class of the controls in your video player. Another option is document.getElementById("myVideo").controls = false;

Comment: IE11. document.getElementById worked. Thanks Rado.

Comment: No problem Ryan, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").controls = false;
```